# Google map in zurb foundation 5 not clear

Tags: google-maps, zurb-foundation

Need help !!
I am using google map on my web page using zurb foundation 5.
And instead of having : 
[image]
I am having this:
[image]

As you see these two images are different, I do not have any layer above it.
Here is my code where I introduce my map:

```
<div id="map" class="row" data-lat='-18.914872' data-info='Ny Fy Tia' data-lng='47.531612' class="row">

#map
{
    min-height: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 300px;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

Comment: Why you are giving opacity .3 in your #map.. check it out

Comment: I am really idiot I had thousands of lines so I even didn't saw this one. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the opacity to 1 or remove it completely.